# User that can be accessed only from other user account

Tags: permissions, users, account-restrictions

I have a number of users (23) but I want to create another user that can be accessed only from one of the user account to do some specific task. How can I do it. And obviously this user cannot be root. Nobody else must see or have access to this user.

I don't have any idea how to do it, any attempt I did yesterday doesn't satisfy my conditions.

*Update* (explanation) :

It's like a user inside other user. A user (hiddenUser in the graph) that can't only be accessed if you are user2 (graph).
Graph :
- user1
|
- user2
|    |
|     - hiddenUser
|
- user3

Comment: have a look at sudo, e.g. `sudo taskuser ls -l`. try man sudoers. I'll gave more details later.

Comment: I agree with @Archemar Add to that setting up this user account without a password (or with an expired password) so that no one is able to log in as that user. People would still be able to "see" the user account though: a simple `getent passwd` would suffice.

Comment: you can create a new group and add the two users to that group.

Comment: Please elaborate what exactly you have tried yesterday. This will help produce good answers.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "nobody else can see this user" requirement. What in your mind does this actually mean?

Comment: Sounds like you *might* be able to handle it with [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/), but I don't know enough of PAM to say how.